# Webcam not working, black screen

Tags: 20.04, usb, webcam

`lsusb` tells `Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270`.

`ls -la /dev/video*` tells

```
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 juin   2 12:47 /dev/video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 juin   2 12:47 /dev/video1
```

With or without `sudo`, `guvcview -d /dev/video0` tells

```
GUVCVIEW: version 2.0.6
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:869:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:869:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:869:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:869:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
Cannot connect to server socket err = Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Cannot connect to server socket err = Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
Cannot connect to server socket err = Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Ressource temporairement non disponible
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Ressource temporairement non disponible
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Ressource temporairement non disponible
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Ressource temporairement non disponible
```

...and the last line repeats forever.

If I switch to `video1`, I'm told by the GUI that "no video device is found", and I have a list box with twice the same input device (046d:0825). Nothing happens with the second, choosing the first goes back to the log above.

This is an external webcam. The sound works but I have no picture.

`lsb_release -a` tells

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```